# Aggregate DataFrame down to one row using different functions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregation

I have a dataframe with multiple rows, which I'd like to aggregate down, per-column, to a 1-row dataframe, using a different function per-column.

Take the following dataframe, as an example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [2,3]], columns=['A', 'B'])
print(df)
```

Result:

```
   A  B
0  1  2
1  2  3
```

I'd like to aggregate the first column using `sum` and the second using `mean`. There is a convenient [`DataFrame.agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) method which can take a map of column names to aggregation function, like so:

```py
aggfns = {
    'A': 'sum',
    'B': 'mean'
}
print(df.agg(aggfns))
```

However, this results in a `Series` rather than a DataFrame:

```
A    3.0
B    2.5
dtype: float64
```

Among other problems, a series has a single `dtype` so loses the per-column datatype. A series is well-suited to represent a single dataframe column, but not a single dataframe *row*.

I managed to come up with this tortured incantation:

```
df['dummy'] = 0
dfa = df.groupby('dummy').agg(aggfns).reset_index(drop=True)
print(dfa)
```

This creates a dummy column which is 0 everywhere, groups on it, does the aggregation and drops it, which produces the desired result:

```
   A    B
0  3  2.5
```

Certainly there is something better?

Comment: What happens if you put the agg functions in brackets in the dictionary? Or if you used a named aggregation?

Comment: @sammywemmy - I had also tried the "list of one" apprach like `{ 'A' : ['sum'] ...` but this produces an N-row result if there are N different aggregation functions in total (so 2 in my example): one row for each function, with NaN or other missing in most cells where the function didn't apply. What is a "named aggregation"?

Comment: Do you mind to add your expected output?

Comment: ``df.agg(A=('A', 'sum'), B=('B', 'mean'))`` is a named aggregation, but it yields the same thing. @KarlThornton's solution seems like what you are after

Comment: @rpanai I've added the output from my last variant, which is the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Series.to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) + [`DataFrame.T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) (short for [`transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html)):

```
dfa = df.agg(aggfns).to_frame().T
```

Output:

```
>>> dfa
     A    B
0  3.0  2.5
```

Comment: This loses the dtype of the columns as noted in the question: passing though a series squashes all the types down to a single dtype in an unfortunate way (as in, depending on the most specific common type of all the columns). In the resulting frame column `A` has type `float64` but it should be `int64`.

Comment: @BeeOnRope check the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could group by an empty Series instead of creating a new column:

```
dfa = df.assign(d=0).groupby('d').agg(aggfns).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> dfa
   A    B
0  3  2.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly create a new `DataFrame()`

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({'A': [df.A.sum()], 'B': [df.B.mean()]}
   A    B
0  3  2.5
```